# Java, Linux - 2D drawing on a "headless" linux system

Tags: java, linux, headless

I have a sort of a linux "server" which has no desktop envirovment. This machine has a display connected to it and currently it only displays the terminal.

I am wondering if it's possible to make an application in Java which would draw basic 2D objects like lines, circles, text, etc without having to install a full desktop envirovment.

Comment: Juyt to be clear: Do you have X running or not? Do you want to draw on the screen or on another device?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb

Comment: @ammoQ I don't have X running and I'd like to draw on the screen.